# JHipster cannot build after deleting JDK Version

Tags: java, ubuntu, jhipster, java-home

I installed the latest JDK 17, only to notice that my JHipster Version was not compatible with it. Naturally, I decided to delete the JDK. Unfortunately, after that Ubuntu did not seem to recognize my other installed Java Versions.

I ended up adding this to the end of my ~./bashrc:

```
#SETUP JAVA HOME
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I can see the right version of the JDK when doing "java -version", but when I run my **mvnw.sh** JHipster build script, it says

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.

Anything I did wrong? Starting the app with Intellij still works fine...

Comment: Have you sourced your `.bashrc` file in the open terminal session? What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` outputs?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! It outputs "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64"

Comment: What does `which java` command outputs? Have you installed a JDK or a JRE?

Comment: which java is empty -- I believe I installed the JDK.

Comment: Could you list the contents of the new installed JDK folder? How comes you said `java -version` outputs 11 as version and the shell is unable to recognize it?

Comment: Ahh sorry, it was because I accidentally changed the java path for a test. Which java with the provided path outputs the following: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" .... the contents of that new folder (ls) shows "bin  conf  docs  include  jmods  legal  lib  man  release"

Comment: Would you mind adding the full output log for running `./mvnw.sh` in a clean terminal window?

Comment: (base) marc@marc-Lenovo-V130-15IKB:~/projects/my-project$ sudo ./mvnw
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute 
(base) marc@marc-Lenovo-V130-15IKB:~/projects/my-project$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64